# When scroll, dont move width screen ( position: fixed; )

Tags: html, css

I have a `<h1>` over a image with a gradient overlay. To put the text over that, I used a `position: fixed;`

But when I scroll it moves with the screen, but I want it to stay at the place I put it.
I hope I explained it well.

Does anyone have an idea?

Image CSS:

```
.pt-page-header__image {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.pt-gradient-overlay {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -60px;
    max-width: 900px;
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;

    &::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right , $brand-2-color, transparent);
    }
}
```

Text CSS:

```
.pt-page-header__wrapper__content {
            max-width: 600px;
            position: fixed;
        }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="pt-gradient-overlay">
        <img src="https://scu.mb.ca/SCU/media/Images/Content%20Images/content-checking-account.jpg" alt="placeholder" class="pt-page-header__image">
    </div>
<div class="pt-page-header__wrapper__content">
    <h1 class="pt-page-header__title">test</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Add Your Code Here

Comment: Can you please add your html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `position: absolute` instead

```css
.relative {
position: relative;
}
.pt-page-header__image {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.pt-gradient-overlay {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -60px;
  max-width: 900px;
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  &::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, $brand-2-color, transparent);
  }
}

.pt-page-header__wrapper__content {
  max-width: 600px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
  <div class="pt-gradient-overlay">
    <img src="https://scu.mb.ca/SCU/media/Images/Content%20Images/content-checking-account.jpg" alt="placeholder" class="pt-page-header__image">
  </div>
  <div class="pt-page-header__wrapper__content">
    <h1 class="pt-page-header__title">test</h1>
  </div>
```

Comment: I tried that, but then the ```<h1>``` it doesn't go over it image.

Comment: in your css it's `.pt-page-header__wrapper__content` not `.pt-header__wrapper__content`